# Why does Akka HTTP default to as little diagnostic informaiton as possible?

Tags: java, akka, akka-http

More of a philosophical question

I am building a new HTTP service with Akka HTTP in Java and in my unit test I get back

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Unexpected status code!
Expected :200 OK
Actual   :400 Bad Request
 <Click to see difference>


at akka.http.javadsl.testkit.JUnitRouteTestBase$$anon$1.reportDetails(JUnitRouteTest.scala:47)
at akka.http.javadsl.testkit.JUnitRouteTestBase$$anon$1.assertEquals(JUnitRouteTest.scala:30)
at akka.http.javadsl.testkit.TestRouteResult.assertEqualsKind(TestRouteResult.scala:227)
at akka.http.javadsl.testkit.TestRouteResult.assertStatusCode(TestRouteResult.scala:136)
at com.mastercard.pci.enclave.ServerTest.testTokenize(ServerTest.java:48)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:48)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: Unexpected status code! expected:<200 OK> but was:<400 Bad Request>
at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:834)
at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:118)
at akka.http.javadsl.testkit.JUnitRouteTestBase$$anon$1.$anonfun$assertEquals$1(JUnitRouteTest.scala:30)
at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
at akka.http.javadsl.testkit.JUnitRouteTestBase$$anon$1.reportDetails(JUnitRouteTest.scala:44)
... 29 more
```

Which in no way addresses the issue of why is this a `Bad Request`?

After researching Akka HTTP 'Rejections' there seems to be no simple way to say "Akka, just tell me why you are rejecting the request!"

It seems to me that default operation of starting an Akka project should be maximum diagnostics, and you configure less diagnostics as you get closer to production status. However, the default of Akka is to provide minimum diagnostics, and make you research endlessly to figure out, how to figure out what is wrong.

Sorry if this seems like a bit of a rant, but my genuine question is why does Akka provide such minimal diagnostics out of the box?

Comment: You are only logging the HTTP status code - this is what 400 means - “Bad Request”. To get more information, you need to look at the body of the response...

Comment: Thanks. Using `System.out.println(TestRouteResult.response());` helps to that end, but does not answer the bigger question of why Akka HTTP is so minimal on diagnostic information in the first place. I seem to recall there is some way to configure Akka HTTP logging to be more helpful, but still searching for examples.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a question of this nature can be accurately answered by anyone except the primary contributors to the library.  A "why" requires the intent of the creators.  However, I will try to take a crack at it...

**"Why is this a Bad Request?"**

There are many many many reasons why a specific `HttpRequest` would not match a `Route` specified in akka.  Just to give a few examples:

1. The `Path` of the request may not match any of the path matchers.
2. The ["Accept Encoding"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Request_fields) header of the request may not match a
   compression scheme that the server is capable of.
3. The [request method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) could be wrong.
4. ...

Even worse, the Route creator can combine requirements in various ways.  For example, if the route is defined as

```
val route = 
  post {
    path("only" / "match" / "post" / "request") {
      complete("good post request")
    }
  } ~ 
  get {
    path("only" / "match" / "get / "request") {
      complete("good get request")
    }
  }
```

What if the client sends a `GET` with the path `"/only/match/post/request"`?  Then should the diagnostic information say the request has the wrong method or the wrong path?  Both are true and both are false!

**Diagnostic Information**

It is the responsibility of the server creator to provide "diagnostic" information:

```
val route = 
  get {
    complete("good user, only get requests are matched")
  } ~ 
  complete(405 -> "bad user, only get requests are matched")
```

I agree with your statement that the question is "a bit of a rant".  The question seems akin to the question: "why won't akka write my server for me?"